# After massacre at party, flesh pieces join with each other to become a big pile of flesh

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw a part of some movie in television when I was 12-13 years old (in 2006 or 2007). I can't remember much but the scene was a guy having dinner or breakfast with some freak or ghosts (unlike wrong turn guys) and a freak put his spoon into mouth and the spoon penetrates his throat comes out from backside of his head. Then he pulls it …

And I remember at the ending of the movie or near the ending, some party was going on and something happens and the guy cuts people with a chainsaw-type thing and the whole party hall becomes full of flesh and blood and then those flesh pieces started to join with each other and created a big pile of flesh and maybe the pile of flesh was talking.

At the end the police or fire brigade came, but I'm 50% sure that there was a burning building and there was a baby crying on a roof top or something.

Can anyone tell me the movie name? I'm dying to watch it.

Comment: “I'm dying to watch it.” I bet!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is [**Braindead**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Braindead), AKA [**Dead Alive**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103873/), an early work by Peter Jackson (now better known for the Lord of the Rings and Hobbit movies).

[The spoon scene may be viewed on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMOPND8kN44), as can [the ending scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5XbPTvxryA).